# Accounts page has question/answer numbering errors, and also duplicates of an account

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, linked-accounts, stackexchange.com

For https://stackexchange.com/users/5146076/gigili?tab=accounts

at current time of writing, the first two entries (Mathematics) are repeated, the second with obviously incorrect question and answer totals. Though the first one is wrong too. The third and fourth entries are obviously wrong too.

Also, in https://stackexchange.com/users/13717/derobert?tab=accounts

the entry for Sound Design has 0 answers, when in fact there are 2.

See screenshot: [image]

Comment: Did you have an account merge?

Comment: @Tim who, me? They're not my accounts.

Comment: One of these is a user merge/unmerge side-effect. The other is (probably) something going wrong around the time of the Sound Design site import. I'm looking into fixing 'em up.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for pointing these out!

Once in a while we have problems with the aggregator that helps us put the network profile together from individual site profiles. We've put in additional checks and retries over time, but it's not fool-proof.

These two profiles should be fixed up and all set. The views will update eventually once the caches refresh.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the problem. I thought these might be instances of a more general problem. Was this the case, or not?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sort of, but not really. Both of these are side-effects of very infrequent operations. It's not a widespread issue.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification.